# Python requests double of everything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to make a program to get Spotify profile pictures. I can get the URLs for pictures but the problem is there are 2 of every URL.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


list = ["https://open.spotify.com/user/0n7zzdkxmt0ldpo1kqugwca67",
        "https://open.spotify.com/user/1l23d3k5yq2v9ey191zp8uqxr",
]

for i in list:
    response = requests.get(i)

    html_content = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"bg lazy-image"}):
        print(i.get("data-src"))
```

And this is the result:

```
https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6775700000ee85202880a205b627a7e6f25659
https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6775700000ee85202880a205b627a7e6f25659
https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6775700000ee85da40dde3363ed185d5e48a0a
https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6775700000ee85da40dde3363ed185d5e48a0a

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question is how can I print only one of them if they are the same?

Comment: you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases, you simply convert the iterable to a **set**:

```
    for i in set(soup.find_all("div",{"class":"bg lazy-image"})):
       print(i.get("data-src"))
```

by doing so, all duplicates inside of the iterable **get eradicated**.

I would strongly recommend reading up on **Python's datastructures**:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: You're storing divs into a set, while removing duplicate _urls_ is expected.

Comment: @bereal Ehm I just ran your code and the result is identical with the given input

Comment: it's because divs _happen_ to be identical besides the `data-src` attribute. If at some point they have some unique attribute, like `id`, the result will be different.

Comment: Thank you both i fixed the code now i will look into learning sets.

Answer (score 2):

I'd convert them into a set to remove the duplicates:

```
divs = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"bg lazy-image"})
urls = set(d.get('data-src') for d in divs)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is just to check if the URL equals the last URL.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


list = ["https://open.spotify.com/user/0n7zzdkxmt0ldpo1kqugwca67",
        "https://open.spotify.com/user/1l23d3k5yq2v9ey191zp8uqxr",
]

for i in list:
    response = requests.get(i)
    html_content = response.content

    url = None
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"bg lazy-image"}):
        if i.get("data-src") != url:
            url = i.get("data-src")
            print(url)
```

Comment: what if there are 3 urls and the first and last are the same?

Comment: That's based on the assumption about urls order in a page.

Comment: There's at least a couple of assumptions here but it works with the sample data provided. But @bereal solution is better.